# Closed-ness of $R(I-K)$ in the Fredholm alternative

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Here $R$ and $N$ denote the range and the null space respectively. I need someone to tell me why letting $k_j\to\infty$ yields a contradiction, and why we can find $u_k\in[N(I-K)]^\perp$ that solves $u_k-K(u_k)=v_k$. Thank you all.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, note that $(u_{k_j},u)\to(u,u)$ since the inner product $(\cdot,u)$ is continuous. By uniqueness of limits, we obtain $(u,u)=0$. Hence, $u$ is the zero vector in $H$. Given that $||u_{k_j}||=1$ for each $j$, $\{u_{k_j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ cannot converge to the zero vector. This is a contradiction.

For the second question, we conclude from (i) that $H=N(I-K)\oplus[N(I-K)]^\perp$. The result is now obvious.